# Assigning, sending, and retrieving user specific ID tags using Firebase and Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, user-input

I have two different user classes in my Firebase database that I want to "connect" by assigning a unique 5 character code to each user when created. Essentially one user class will have the ability to type a unique code into a text field which will then be compared to the available users in the other user class. Is there a way to establish this sort of system using Swift 4 and Firebase?

```
  let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:100, y:400, width: 150.00, height:30.00))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    //80, g: 101, b: 161
    button.setTitle("Register", for: UIControlState())
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState())
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(verifyCode), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

    //setupView()



@objc func verifyCode(){
    let code = UITextField.text
    let reference = Database.database().reference().child("doctor").child("Code")
        if code == reference.key {
            print ("success")
        }
        print("Form is not valid")
        return
```

I tried a basic version of the concept by manually inserting a value into one user class that should check and verify the corresponding value assigned in the database. But I have run into the issue of:

"Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '(UITextField) -> (UITextRange) -> String?' and 'String'"

This error shows up next to the "if code == reference.key" line. 
I am sure there is a different way to approach this issue but I am not having any luck in finding a solution. (I am relatively new to programming so sorry if this is something very basic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like there may be more than one issue in the code because I don't think `reference.key` is going to get you the value you're looking for. That being said, the immediate issue is that the function `verifyCode()` isn't checking the UITextField of your class. Instead of `UITextField`, you should use the name of your UITextField. For example:

```
@IBOutlet var myTextField: UITextField!

// ...
@objc func verifyCode(){
  let code = myTextField.text
  let reference = Database.database().reference().child("doctor").child("Code")
    if code == reference.key {
      print ("success")
    }
  print("Form is not valid")
  return
}
```

Going back to the other issue, given

```
let reference = Database.database().reference().child("doctor").child("Code")
```

`reference.key` will just give you the key. In this case, `"Code"`. You may need to look more into [the guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) and play with [some examples](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios) to get the behavior you're looking for.